# c++ access violation on send message

Tags: c++, winapi

I have problem with one program. When I sent message which simulating click button:

```
SendMessage(mainHWND, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM( GetDlgCtrlID( btnHWND ) , BN_CLICKED ), (LPARAM) btnHWND );
```

Program got my message box with error like "Access violation at address ---------- in module
`someApp.exe'. Write of address ------."

I try other messages like:

```
Send, Post and SendNotify Message(btnHWND, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0,0));
Send, Post and SendNotify Message(btnHWND, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(0,0));
```

and

```
Send, Post and SendNotify Message(btnHWND, WM_COMMAND, 1, 0);
```

All work but program return error :(

But if I sent:

```
SendMessage(textBoxHWND, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LPARAM("test"));
```

Work without error.

Can someone please explain ?

EDIT.
Is must be done in the background.

EDIT2.
btnHWND is handle to button which I click, mainHWND is handle to windows where is button.

Comment: Looks like your `this` object is invalid hence you get access violation when you try to do `GetDlgCtrlID`.

Comment: What is `btnHWND`? On the whole, there isn't enough information available to answer this question.

Comment: @MatsPetersson yep. OP just should check whether the `this`, `brnHWND`, `mainHWND` are valid objects.

Comment: @OP you can use `IsWindow` function from WinAPI or its MFC analogue.

Comment: btnHWND is handle to button which I click, mainHWND is handle to windows where is button.
And this handles are valid on 100%.
Where is problem :( ?

Comment: Are you sure that the error occurs on that line? Is it perhaps something in the main window's handling of the message that's giving you that error?

Comment: Yes I am sure because this one line integrates in"someApp.exe"